# accessing multidimensional array in laravel blade

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to access the 'cat' value in my array below, coming from my controller.

If I dump $tempCategories it shows the array correctly but my html is showing nothing for some reason.

Am I not accessing the element correctly?

I expect to see

```
Wood
Metal
```

controller.php

```
  $tempCategories = array(
        0 => array(
            'cat' => 'Wood'
        ),
        1 => array(
            'cat' => 'Metal'
        ),
    );
```

blade.php

```
@foreach($tempCategories as $cat)
<h5>{{$cat->cat}}</h5>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to access an array as object

Replace

```
<h5>{{$cat->cat}}</h5>
```

With

```
<h5>{{$cat['cat']}}</h5>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access it with arrow operator - convert your array to object or collection first (in your controller)

```
$object = (object) $array;
```

Or

```
$collection = collect($array);
```